# How to select the records with the particular date day or today's date and increment highest sequence number (int or id) in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I need to  select the records with the particular date day and increment highest sequence number (int or id) in LINQ, how todo this?

Answer (score -1):

Select your date day or **DateTime.UtcNow.Date** or **DateTime.Today**

```
_Dbcontext.DbTable.SequenceIntegerColumn = _Dbcontext.DbTable.Where(x => x
.DateColumn.Value.Day == DateTime.UtcNow.Date)
.Max(n => n.SequenceIntegerColumn) + 1;
```

or

```
_Dbcontext.DbTable.SequenceIntegerColumn = _Dbcontext.DbTable.Where(x => x
.DateColumn.Value.Day == DateTime.Today)
.Max(n => n.SequenceIntegerColumn) + 1;
```